# How to validate server responses against swagger generated java models

Tags: java, json, swagger

I use POJO models, generated from swagger.yaml file in my project (automated API tests). However, I don't use any other stuff that `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` generates.

When I fire a request, I just put the server response into the generated POJO and later i can get any data from this and compare to anything I expect to be there.

But the problem is, test are not failing, when, for example, some required field descripbed in swagger is absent in the server response. They fail if only I manually try to get the value of this field from the object.

How to make them fail when something is missing, or when some field has wrong type, or even when something  not described in swgger is returned by the server?